# While loop need to create new div every 5 elements

Tags: php, while-loop

I've got a while loop that displays 50 logos. But what I need is another loop that creates a new div(.autogrid_wrapper .cte .block) every 5 images.

```
<?php
                        $cn = 1;
                        while($result->next()) {
                            if ($cn % 5 == 0) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="autogrid_wrapper cte block">
                                <div class="inner">
                                <?php } ?>
                                <div class="ce_card autogrid-type_cte n5 one_fifth autogrid_mode_auto autogrid <?php echo $class2; ?> <?php echo $class; ?> block">
                                    <div class="card_wrapper">
                                        <a class="download_image" title="<?php echo $result->name; ?>"
                                        <div class="ce_image attribute image">
                                            <div class="ce_image block">
                                                <figure class="image_container">
                                                    <img src="<?php echo $imageVar->path; ?>" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='files/Intershop/media/images/customers/<?php echo $rest; ?>.png'" title="<?php echo $entry->field('name')->value(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $entry->field('name')->value(); ?>" >
                                                </figure>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear autogrid_clear"></div>
                                <?php if ($cn % 5 == 0) { ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <?php
                                }
                                $cn++;
                                ?>
                        <?php } ?>
```

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: What  have you got ? I mean you didn't point out what's problem with your code, what you have got through these code.

Comment: I've got this: https://jsfiddle.net/4t7z2aq2/ but I dont know how to code it with the: while($result->next())

Comment: You wanna create  `div(.autogrid_wrapper .cte .block) ` before 1st item and close this div after `while` walk through 5th item?

Comment: Yes, just like in the forech loop, that one works.

Answer (score 2):

Ok , after ask you in comments I know what's your purpose.
You wanna `print` `div(.autogrid_wrapper .cte .block)` before 1st item and close this div after `while` walk through 5th item and so on.

```
$cn = 1;
while($result->next()) {
    if($cn % 5 == 1) {
        //div(.autogrid_wrapper .cte .block)
    }

    // HTML wraps image

    if($cn % 5 == 0) {
        //print the close tag of div(.autogrid_wrapper .cte .block)
    }
    $cn ++;
}
```

Embed this flow control in your code, I think this will work.

Comment: @fr3d  Sorry I omit `$cn ++` in my code, see my edit.

Comment: It works, awsome but now I saw, every first and fith element need the class .first and .last, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/y49baq7o/

Comment: Then add these class in the same way,  it still work on the new demand :) BTW, please mark this answer as correct, when other guys search and find this post it will help them too.

Comment: But I've got one little problem, sometim,es I've got 5 images, sometimes more and sometimes less. I think, if there are less than 5 images, the closing tag doesn't work and the divs arn't closing.

Comment: Oh, you need get the  images count through another query and then modify the last condition to `$cn %5 == 0 OR $cn == $image_count`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108812/discussion-between-kevin-yan-and-fr3d).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this hope it's helps

```
<?php 
$cn = 1;
while($result->next()) { 
     if ($cn % 5 == 0) { //check if number is divided by 5 like 5,10,15 etc
           //new div'
     }

    YOUR HTML

      if ($cn % 5 == 0) {
           //close div'
     } 
     $cn++;
     } ?>
```

Comment: The loop is not really working, I changed the code in my post to the current version.